# Is there any bitwise multiplication algorithm that is sub O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithms, number-theory, multiplication

The following program implements a simple algorithm for binary multiplication:

```
-- Numbers as infinite streams of bits, least significant bits first
data Bits
  = O Bits
  | I Bits

-- Increments a number
suc :: Bits -> Bits
suc (O xs) = I xs
suc (I xs) = O (suc xs)

-- Adds two numbers
add :: Bits -> Bits -> Bits
add (O xs) (O ys) =      (O (add xs ys))
add (O xs) (I ys) =      (I (add xs ys))
add (I xs) (O ys) =      (I (add xs ys))
add (I xs) (I ys) = (suc (I (add xs ys)))

-- Multiplies two numbers
mul :: Bits -> Bits -> Bits
mul (O xs) ys =        (O (mul xs ys))
mul (I xs) ys = add ys (O (mul xs ys))
```

(The complete program can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/MaiaVictor/fccb0ac2ac4d6b1fbe6a933d22214df8).)

This algorithm, although simple, has `O(N^2)` complexity. Are there similarly simple algorithms with lower complexities?

Answer (score 3):

Is [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) simple enough? It's complexity is $O(n^{1.59})$.

Comment: I wasn't aware it applies to binary representations (i.e., no built-in 32-bit mul).

Comment: @MaiaVictor you can split the operands recursively until the algorithm would be more expensive than the naive one after which you go back to naive.